# torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder is giving me a 3x3 grid of images intead of 1 image

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

[image: my code and output]

I can't figure out why it's giving me 9 gray images in a 3x3 grid instead of just one color image (original image is not gray and has RGB channels). I have spent 5 hours on this. Thanks for the help.

Here is my code

```
test_path = "asl_data/test/" #path to the folder
test_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(test_path, transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor())
def test32():
    for x, y in test_data:
        print(x.shape)
        x = x.reshape(533,800,3)
        plt.axis("off")
        plt.imshow(x)
        plt.show()
        plt.axis("off")
        plt.imshow(x[:176,:267,:])
        break
test32()
```

Comment: does it happen on any image folder?

Comment: @shai yes, all images in every folder

Comment: what version of `torchvision` are you using?

Comment: @shai, version is '0.11.3+cu113'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic.

You `reshape` instead of `permute`.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51143206/1714410) on the *crucial* difference between the two.

Fix:

```py
x = x.permute((1, 2, 0))
plt.imshow(x)
```

A simple visual example:

```py
x, y = test_data[0]  # take one image
x.shape  # torch.Size([3, 223, 320])

# see the difference
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[0].imshow(x.numpy().reshape(223, 320, 3))
ax[0].set_title('Wrong reshape instead of permute')

ax[1].imshow(x.permute((1,2,0)))
ax[1].set_title('correctly permuting')
```

[image]

Comment: ah, Thank you for the answer. I spent so much time reading the documentation of torchvision.dataset and torchvision.transform. I feel so stupid now.